# Eclipse Unable to create instance of annotation processor org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate-annotations, annotation-processing, java-11

I have a project with Hibernate annotations and annotation processing enabled in eclipse.

Once I switch to JAVA 11 Open JDK, the annotation processing is not working.

Below is the full error:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.10.0.I20181206-0815
java.version=11.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/shamalk/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/shamalk/.eclipse_keyring

org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core
Error
Fri Dec 28 18:03:24 MYT 2018
Unable to create instance of annotation processor org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.xml.JpaDescriptorParser.<init>(JpaDescriptorParser.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor.init(JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.apt.pluggable.core.dispatch.IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.discoverNextProcessor(IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.round(RoundDispatcher.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.apt.pluggable.core.dispatch.IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processAnnotations(Compiler.java:940)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 27 more
```

I have tried adding the following JAXB libraries to my project as a solution with no success, but not sure if eclipse annotation processor refers to project classpath for it's dependancies.

Any help is appreciated.